# How can I accept large file uploads of around 250mb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, cloud, dropbox

How can I accept large file uploads of around 250mb ?

http://dropitto.me/ seems ok, but it only allows up to 75MB uploads, it requires your actual dropbox account password, and it does not use HTTPS for authentication - so a few red flags there.

I have a Dropbox Pro account and EC2 and S3 resources. I'm looking for a method to allow non-technical users to send files between 100 - 250mb.

I'm not crazy about using FTP because I think it might be too technical for some users to set up. One option might be to ask them to register for a dropbox.com account and install the client and share a folder. Or share a folder with them to initiate the process.

**But the real reason I'm asking this on StackOverflow is because I hope that there is some library that is really useful for doing this kind of stuff** - and would be fast for the end users since the backbone could be "on the cloud". I don't really care what language it's written in.

Also let me just say that I'm not crazy about the idea of using rapidshare.com or megaupload.com or a service like that, but let me know if you would support those as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://kicksend.com - they allow up to a certain amount in the browser, but they have applications for mac/windows which allow for basically unlimited file transfer very easily.